# Can't find the id of parent element of clicked element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the `id` of the parent of element of the event on which the `mousedown` event was performed. I am using the following code:

```
$(document).on("mousedown",function(e) {  
    var id1 = $(e.target).closest("div").attr('id');
    console.log(id1);
});
```

The output of this is always `undefinded`. I tried this also:

```
$(document).on("mousedown",function(e) {  
    var id1 = $(e.target).closest("div");
    console.log(id1);
});
```

This is the output

```
[div.addmap, prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: div.addmap]
```

What can I do to get the `id` attribute of the parent element? `addmap` is the `id` of the parent `div`.

Comment: We need to see your HTML to be able to help you.

Comment: html pleaseee if possible a fiddle aswell?

Comment: You could use the jQuery .parent() function.

Comment: not all elements have an id, so the function is flawed to begin with - and if I'm reading the last output correctly, addmap is the CLASS of the parent div

Comment: This is kind of lame, but i think the problem is due to me confusing id and class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on("mousedown",function(e) {  
    var id1=$(e.target).parent().attr('id');
    console.log(id1);
});
```

Comment: I don't see how this is any different to what you already had, given that `closest()` goes infinite levels up the DOM, but `parent()` only goes 1 level. This code is more restrictive, so how can it work when `closest()` didn't?

Comment: @Rory: as you already said, there was probably also something else the matter... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The reason you cannot find a parent is, that you have bound the event-listener to the document itself. If you supply a second argument in the form of

```
$(document).on('mousedown', 'img', function(e){...})
```

You will bind the event listener to all `<img>` elements for example. Then clicking on an image will produce the desired result. Instead if `'img'` you could also use `'img,p,span,div'` which would bind the listener to all elements being of one if the types specified.

If you don't want to be specific you could of course also use `'*'` binding it to all elements of the document.

Comment: `e.target` will point to the element that raised the event which bubbled, it won't always be the `document`, example: http://jsfiddle.net/2y6me2t4/. Event delegation is not necessarily required here, although the question is so poor and vague it's hard to tell exactly what the problem is.

Comment: The form `$(document).on(<event type>,function(){...})` however will bind the event listener *only* to the document itself, not to any of its children. To do that you will need the second argument to be a selector string.

Comment: that's correct, but due to event bubbling, that's not a problem in this case. In fact, it's pretty much what a delegated event handler does anyway. Did you see the example I created?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't run the fiddle on my 5yo iPod. But one thing remains: using on() in the OP's way does *not*. delegate the event.

Comment: Yes it does. Event delegation in jQuery is just event bubbling, and checking the element that raised the event against the selector provided. When you can, check the fiddle I added and you will see it working. Here's another example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/2y6me2t4/1/

Comment: Thanks for the examples! I will certainly check them out. Always good to learn something new. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As I'm assuming binding to the document is intentional in order to register clicks anywhere on the page and get the closest div, the following should do the trick:

I've taken onboard Jaromanda X's observation that you seem to be looking for a parent class rather than id (`context: div.addmap`)

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j86rn2mh/1/

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on("mousedown", function (e) {
var closestDiv = $(e.target).closest('div');
var closestDivClass = closestDiv.parent().attr('class');
console.log(closestDivClass);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='addMap'>
<div id='targetDiv'>CLICK ME</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.addMap {
height: 200px;
width:200px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
}

div#targetDiv {
height: 100px;
width:100px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: yellow;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $('#elm').click(function(){
    var parentElm = $(this).parent('tagname_or_class_or_id').attr('id');
  });
});
```

Try this one, It should work :)